# Quadratic Drawing

Tags: quadratics

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the shading
This is the picture:

[image]

Here are my equations so far:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knew what domain and range constraints I could add to make only the inside of the petal shaded.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a question about how to use Desmos(?), which I don't think is really on-topic here, but here is one possible [Desmos solution](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z0kaufblre).  It should also be noted that Desmos can plot implicitly defined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Its more natural to use more general restrictions than rectangular ones (I also don't know how to make desmos plot the intersection of two sets any other way) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yzpuhh6cf2

[image: How about this?]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you know how to alter the constraints I have for the equations above to make the shape.

Comment: @mjj you'll need to use more complicated restrictions, because as I said, I don't know how to make desmos plot intersections of two sets (which is what you want) any other way